Extraer texto alternado con el comando grep y expresiones regulares
A través de este comando estoy extrayendo información sobre las entidades bancarias existentes en España y sus correspondientes códigos:
curl -sX GET 'https://www.bde.es/webbe/es/estadisticas/otras-clasificaciones/clasificacion-entidades/listas-instituciones-financieras/listas-instituciones-financieras-monetarias-pais/lista-mfi-es.html' | egrep 'ES[0-9]{2}' 

El resultado de ese código es un texto como el siguiente que se repite por cada entidad bancaria:
<tr><td headers="code">ES8840</td><td headers="lei">9598000WTZEQB8MJGF25</td><td headers="nom">Xfera Consumer Finance, E.F.C. S.A.</td><td headers="cat">Otra institución</td><td headers="dir">PS DE LOS MELANCOLICOS, 14, 28005, MADRID</td><td headers="inf" class="centrado">No</td><td headers="mat" class="centrado"></td><td headers="cods" class="centrado">8840</td></tr>

Mi objetivo es obtener el código del banco, es decir, ES8840 (para el caso mostrado) y el nombre del banco, es decir, Xfera Consumer Finance, E.F.C. S.A.
Lo he hecho eliminando el texto que hay entre código de banco y nombre con el comando sed y luego con un grep extrayendo el texto que me interesa de este modo:
<COMANDO ANTERIOR> | sed -E s'/<\/td.*nom">//' | grep -oE 'ES[0-9]{4}[^<]*'

Resultado:

Funciona bien, pero me preguntaba si es posible hacerlo en una sola expresión con grep. Desconozco si en una sola regex puedo descartar trozos de texto intermedios entre dos extremos que quiero obtener.
Agradecería asesoramiento si lo que planteo es viable.

He visto que algunos de esos bancos tienen más de 4 dígitos después del ES.  ¿Estas seguro que solo quieres esos?

Brutal masterguru, es justo lo que necesitaba. Sí, con ES seguida de 4 dígitos es suficiente, no necesito más.

No lo tengo tan claro, quizas no me he expresado bien. Tal como tu lo pides, te saltas algunos registros como estos: ESA86969607|BIP&Drive EDE, S.A, ESW0230061D|CA AUTO BANK, SPA, SUCURSAL EN ESPAÑA, ESV63050835|CAIXABANK MONETARIO RENDIMIENTO, FI, y unos 10 más aproximadamente. Si no quieres saltártelos, elimina la segunda línea de mi respuesta y te apareceran.

Está claro. Solo necesito aquellos que empiecen por ES y tengan 4 números, que es la codificación estándar de las sucursales en España. Muchas gracias.

Puedes hacer algo así, usando -P en el grep (si tu grep tiene soporte para expresiones Perl) y el comando paste pues siempre van a ser dos resultados los que pretendes encontrar
curl -sX GET 'https://www.bde.es/webbe/es/estadisticas/otras-clasificaciones/clasificacion-entidades/listas-instituciones-financieras/listas-instituciones-financieras-monetarias-pais/lista-mfi-es.html' | \
egrep 'ES[0-9]{2}' | \
grep -Po '(?<=<td headers="code">).*?(?=<\/td>)|(?<=<td headers="nom">).*?(?=<\/td>)' | \
paste -d"|" - -


No con grep, porque grep solo matchea y no procesa texto alterándolo, y tu quieres algo como selecciona, eliminar, y presentar. Pero puedes con Perl.
Primero probemos esta regex:
\<td headers\="code"\>(\w+?)\<\/td\>.*?"nom"\>(.*?)\<\/td

Donde básicamente te busca lo que está inmediatamente a la derecha de los tags "code" y "nom", y termina de matchear antes del cierre del tag inmediato.
Esto te lo guarda en dos grupos; uno alfanumerico nongreedy ("\w+?"), y el otro nongreedy para que frene antes del inmediato cierre de tag (".*?")
Un poco más claro en Regex101.
Ahora metamoslo en Perl de la forma, perl -ne '/<regex>/ && print "$1|$2\n"'
curl \
  -sX GET \
  --url 'https://www.bde.es/webbe/es/estadisticas/otras-clasificaciones/clasificacion-entidades/listas-instituciones-financieras/listas-instituciones-financieras-monetarias-pais/lista-mfi-es.html' \
  | perl -ne '/\<td headers\="code"\>(\w+?)\<\/td\>.*?"nom"\>(.*?)\<\/td/ && print "$1|$2\n"'

Y nos resulta algo asi:
ES0241|A&G BANCO, S.A.
ES2080|Abanca Corporacion Bancaria, S.A.
ES8620|Abanca Servicios Financieros E.F.C., S.A.
ES1535|AKF Bank GmbH & Co Kg, Sucursal en España
ES0011|Allfunds Bank, S.A.
...

Nota: no parsees html o xml usando regex, es mala idea
Para esto puedes usar otra librería que se dedique a parsear archivos html, yo usaré xmllint:
$ xmllint --html --xpath '//td[@headers="code" or @headers="nom"]/text()' lista.html 2> /dev/null | awk 'ORS=NR%2?"|":RS'

y obtendremos algo como:
ES0241|A&amp;G BANCO, S.A.
ES2080|Abanca Corporacion Bancaria, S.A.
ES8620|Abanca Servicios Financieros E.F.C., S.A.
ES1535|AKF Bank GmbH &amp; Co Kg, Sucursal en España
ES0011|Allfunds Bank, S.A.
ES0200|ANDBANK ESPAÑA BANCA PRIVADA, S.A.
ES0136|Aresbank, S.A.
ES3183|Arquia Bank, S.A.
ES1541|Attijariwafa Bank Europe, Sucursal en España
ES0061|Banca March, S.A.
...


Brutalísimo Cuauhtli. Muchas gracias por tu amplia descripción y por la recomendación de esa librería. La probaré sin duda.

El xmllint, que es claramente el comando correcto, parece que esta machacando el & en la primera linea: &amp; en vez de &. Dado que la salida no es HTML, no creo que será deseado. Quizás hay alguna opción?

en general es mala idea intentar parsear HTML con expresiones regulares. Es posible, pero realmente complicado hacerlo bien. Eso dicho, en tu caso, con los datos que has mostrado, puedes hacer algo como (asumiendo GNU grep):
$ curl -sX GET 'https://www.bde.es/webbe/es/estadisticas/otras-clasificaciones/clasificacion-entidades/listas-instituciones-financieras/listas-instituciones-financieras-monetarias-pais/lista-mfi-es.html' | 
  grep -oP 'headers="(code|nom)">\K[^<]+' | head
ES0241
A&G BANCO, S.A.
ES2080
Abanca Corporacion Bancaria, S.A.
ES8620
Abanca Servicios Financieros E.F.C., S.A.
ES1535
AKF Bank GmbH & Co Kg, Sucursal en España
ES0011
Allfunds Bank, S.A.

El -o hace que grep solo imprime la parte de cada linea que matchea, y el -P no permite usar Perl Compatible Regular Expressions. Aquí buscamos por headers=" y después o code o nom seguido por ">. La \K significa "olvida lo que has encontrado hasta ahora". entonces acabamos matcheando solo la [^<]+, o sea uno o mas caracteres que no son <. El resultado es el codigo de cada banco seguido por su nombre.
Entonces solo falta juntarles con un |, por lo cual usamos paste -d "|" - -:
$ curl -sX GET 'https://www.bde.es/webbe/es/estadisticas/otras-clasificaciones/clasificacion-entidades/listas-instituciones-financieras/listas-instituciones-financieras-monetarias-pais/lista-mfi-es.html' | 
  grep -oP 'headers="(code|nom)">\K[^<]+' 
    paste -d "|" - - | head
ES0241|A&G BANCO, S.A.
ES2080|Abanca Corporacion Bancaria, S.A.
ES8620|Abanca Servicios Financieros E.F.C., S.A.
ES1535|AKF Bank GmbH & Co Kg, Sucursal en España
ES0011|Allfunds Bank, S.A.

Quita el head para tener el resultado completo:
curl -sX GET 'https://www.bde.es/webbe/es/estadisticas/otras-clasificaciones/clasificacion-entidades/listas-instituciones-financieras/listas-instituciones-financieras-monetarias-pais/lista-mfi-es.html' | 
  grep -oP 'headers="(code|nom)">\K[^<]+' | 
    paste -d "|" - -

Y para limitarte a solo los códigos que consisten de ES y exactamente 4 números:
curl -sX GET 'https://www.bde.es/webbe/es/estadisticas/otras-clasificaciones/clasificacion-entidades/listas-instituciones-financieras/listas-instituciones-financieras-monetarias-pais/lista-mfi-es.html' | 
  grep -oP 'headers="(code|nom)">\K[^<]+' | 
    paste -d "|" - - | grep -P '^ES\d{4}\|'


Esto se llama ser amable, @masterguru, no pesado! Tienes toda la razón, y gracias.  La verdad es que no se si los quiere o no estos el OP ya que a pesar de ser de Irlanda, PFS Card Services tiene como dirección PS DE LA CASTELLANA, 259, 28046, MADRID, pero si que la pregunta buscaba ES[0-9]{4}[^<].

Como puedes ver en los comentarios de la pregunta, yo tambien tenia mis dudas de lo que realmente queria el OP, pero ha sido claro y conciso en su respuesta, así que me ciño a lo que el quiere a pesar de seguir teniendo mis dudas, así como ahora tambien la tuya, que no habia visto.
